# MSP430 UART Reading

Tags: uart, communication, msp430, arduino-uno, baudrate

I'm trying to transmit and receive data between Arduino Uno and CC430. There is no problem with sending data from CC430 to Arduino Uno. I can receive the data on Arduino side. Also I can transmit the data from Arduino Uno but I can't receive the data on CC430 side. My code is given below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <msp430.h> 
#include "cc430x613x.h"

char buffer_0[5] ;
char terminal_read();

int main(void) {
  WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD; // stop watchdog timer
  UART_open();
  while (1) {
    terminal_read();
  }
  return 0;
}

char terminal_read() {
  char my_char;
  my_char = UCA0RXBUF;
  return my_char;
  printf("%s", &my_char);
}

void terminal_write(char *info) {
  unsigned int i;
  unsigned int len = strlen(info) ;
  for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
    UCA0TXBUF=info[i];
    __delay_cycles(10000);
  }
}

void UART_open() {
  P1SEL |= BIT5 + BIT6;
  //UART Settings
  UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;
  UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL0; // ACLK
  UCA0BR0 = 3;   //UCA0BR0 = 3 ; //32Khz / 9600 –>> 3
  UCA0BR1 = 0;   //UCA0BR1=0; // BAUD 9600; ( UCABR1 * 256 ) + CABR0 = UCABRx    see "slau259e.pdf"
  UCA0MCTL = UCBRS0 + UCBRS1; //  see "slau259e.pdf" page 602 //
  // UCA0MCTL =| BIT7 |  BIT6  | BIT5 | BIT4 | BIT3 | BIT2 | BIT1 | BIT0 |
  //          |------- UCBRFx --------------|----UCBRSx----------|UCOS16|
  // for 9600 baudrate at 32kHz UCBRFx = 0 , UCBRSx = 3 , UCOS16 = 0
  //          |  0   | 0      | 0    | 0    | 0    | 1    | 1    | 0    |
  //          0b00000110 = 0x06 = 6
  UCA0CTL1 &=~ UCSWRST;//
  UCA0CTL1 |=  UCDORM;
}

void UART_close() {
  P1SEL &= ~(BIT5 + BIT6);
  P1DIR |= BIT5 + BIT6;
  P1OUT &= ~(BIT5 + BIT6);
  UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;
  UCA0CTL1 &=~ UCDORM;
}

char* String_int(int data) {
  char* ret_data;
  ret_data = ltoa(data, buffer_0, 10 );
  return ret_data;
}
```

Also connection is Rx --> Tx  and Tx -- > Rx, there is no problem with connection.

Edit1 :

This is my new code that just have tried :

```
#include <msp430.h> 
#include "cc430x613x.h"

char buffer_0[5] ;
char terminal_read();

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // stop watchdog timer
    UART_open();
    UCA0IE |= UCRXIE ;

while(1){
    terminal_read();
   // __delay_cycles(1e5);
}


    
    return 0;
}
char terminal_read(){
    char c ;
    while (!(UCA0IFG & UCRXIFG));
    c = UCA0RXBUF ;
    printf("%c" , &c);
            return UCA0RXBUF;
}




void terminal_write(char *info)
{
unsigned int i;


unsigned int len = strlen(info) ;
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{

UCA0TXBUF=info[i];
__delay_cycles(10000);

}
}

void UART_open(){
        P1SEL |= BIT5 + BIT6;
        //UART Settings
        UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;
        UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL0 ; // ACLK
        UCA0BR0=3;   //UCA0BR0 = 3 ; //32Khz / 9600 –>> 3
        UCA0BR1=0;   //UCA0BR1=0; // BAUD 9600;     ( UCABR1 * 256 ) + UCABR0  = UCABRx    see "slau259e.pdf"

        UCA0MCTL=UCBRS0 + UCBRS1 ; //  see "slau259e.pdf" page 602 //
        //UCA0MCTL =| BIT7 |  BIT6  | BIT5 | BIT4 | BIT3 | BIT2 | BIT1 | BIT0 |
        //          |------- UCBRFx --------------|----UCBRSx----------|UCOS16|
        // for 9600 baudrate at 32kHz UCBRFx = 0 , UCBRSx = 3 , UCOS16 = 0
        //          |  0   | 0      | 0    | 0    | 0    | 1    | 1    | 0    |
        //          0b00000110 = 0x06 = 6
        UCA0CTL1  &=~  UCSWRST;//
      //  UCA0CTL1  |=   UCDORM;
}

void UART_close(){

    P1SEL &= ~(BIT5 + BIT6);
    P1DIR |= BIT5 + BIT6;
    P1OUT &= ~(BIT5 + BIT6);
    UCA0CTL1  |=  UCSWRST;
    UCA0CTL1  &=~  UCDORM;

}

char* String_int(int data){
    char* ret_data;
    ret_data      =  ltoa(data , buffer_0 , 10 );
    return ret_data;
}
```

Differences are that :

-I have enabled the 'RX' operation "UCA0IE |= UCRXIE"

-I add the 'Receive Interrupt Flag' to get chars properly. "!(UCA0IFG & UCRXIFG)"

However I couldn't got any chars. 'UCRXIFG'is always reads as '0'.

Comment: You'll need to describe what is not working. From the looks of it, you aren't doing anything with the data you've read. For one thing, your printf statement is after the function return so will be skipped, and secondly you are trying to take a single character and treat it like a null terminated string (which it isn't). Try moving your `printf` before the return statement, and changing it to `printf("%c", my_char)`. I have no idea where printf goes on your CC430, so whether or not that will work I don't know.

Comment: Thanks Tom , you are sure in the terminal_read function I have to take return statement after the printf(). I did it , also I change the '%s' to '%c' , and now I can receive something that 'òòòòòòòòòòòòòò.......' it goes to infinity. In extended ASCII  'ò' character is '162' it's not 255 or 0. Is there any advise for this situation. Thanks for your advises.

Comment: You're also reading without checking whether there is anything to read - you should ahve some function to check if there are any characters available before reading UCA0RXBUF

Comment: This happened to me. I edited the UART configuration code from their TI standard UART code (resource library) for my project. What I didn't know at that time was, Tx and Rx are connected internally if you configure a certain bit in the register UCAxSTATW. Check that. This is what happened to me back in the day. Page 596
https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau445i/slau445i.pdf?ts=1608754734730&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F